# How to automatically connect to VPN with Network-Manager

Tags: network-manager, vpn, cisco, vpnc

I do have a working VPN connection. Now I want this VPN connection to automatically activate when I'm in a certain wireless network. Is there a non-intrusive graphical way using network-manager-applet? If I remember correctly  it worked for a while and doesn't anymore.

I made the wireless-connection in question available for all users for not having to input the password every time.

The CLI program used is vpnc with Hybrid-Auth enabled (cisco VPN-client compatible) from [sroecker's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~sroecker/+archive/ppa)

EDIT: I can' try the answers anymore (because of eduroam) and since no answer seems to gain a majority of votes I'm just gonna leave it unanswered for now until one is upvoted then I'm gonna accept that.

Comment: how are you coming along with this?

Comment: I didn't need it for quite a long time now. Maybe come april on new university.

Comment: Possibel duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/86365

Comment: @fossfreedom not a duplicate exactly because my question is about vpnc rather than openconnect.

Comment: I wrote a short block post on how to block your internet connection unless the VPN is up and running: http://mentat.za.net/blog/2015/01/24/vpn-only-internet/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution suggested by `con-f-use` should work but doesn't, due to a long-standing bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/280571

There are workarounds though. For recent NetworkManager versions, there is a commandline utitility, `nmcli`, that can be edited and saved as something like `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/vpn-up`:

```
#! /bin/bash

REQUIRED_CONNECTION_NAME="<name-of-connection>"
VPN_CONNECTION_NAME="<name-of-vpn-connection>"


activ_con=$(nmcli con status | grep "${REQUIRED_CONNECTION_NAME}")
activ_vpn=$(nmcli con status | grep "${VPN_CONNECTION_NAME}")
if [ "${activ_con}" -a ! "${activ_vpn}" ];
then
    nmcli con up id "${VPN_CONNECTION_NAME}"
fi
```

*[I haven't tested this -- please feel free to test and edit according to results]*

See:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NetworkManager#Use_dispatcher_to_connect_to_a_VPN_after_a_network_connection_is_established has more info.

Comment: note that in 13.04 i had to put that script in /etc/network/if-up.d and fix /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/connection-name according to http://askubuntu.com/questions/198136/error-when-trying-to-connect-to-vpn-on-startup to avoid "No valid VPN secrets" error

Comment: The Arch wiki hack does work in fact!
I tried the script on the arch wiki on july 11th 2013, and modifying it from 'nmcli ...' to 'su [user] -c "nmcli..."' does not work! follow instructions as in the wiki and don't forget the chmod +x ;) cheers!

Comment: The bug mentioned by Hugo Eden (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/280571) has been fixed upstream over 5 months ago. However, I'm still experiencing it in Precise... What gives?

Comment: This did not work for me, so I decided to look into `/var/log/syslog`, and saw the following error:
`Mar  4 13:49:51 oleg-HP nm-dispatcher.action: Cannot execute `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/vpn-up': not executable by owner.`
The solution would be to `sudo chmod 755 /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/vpn-up`

Answer (score 18):

You can find VPN auto-connect option in the `nm-connection-editor` GUI in the individual saved Wi-Fi settings. In Ubuntu 14.04 you can find it under:

*System settings* -> *Network* -> *Wi-Fi* or *Lan* -> *Settings* (General tab) -> *Auto connect to VPN...*

(Since Gnome 42, this path leads to a new simplified menu, but the complete one can still be accessed through `nm-connection-editor` directly)

[image: Screenshot of GUI]

After saving, a `secondaries=` line is added in your configuration file in the `[connection]` section.  It will contain a list of secondary connection UUIDs to be activated. The configuration file is usually `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`.

This information can be useful if you need to activate more than one secondary connection. You can add multiple connection UUIDs in the configuration file separated by `;`, even though the GUI (at the moment: 2022) does not allow to select more than one entry.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Very unintuitive tho. I saw that the option was greyed out in my VPN connection config, and I didn't think it might be an option for connecting to a different connection profile.

Answer (score 13):

I was able to get this working on Ubuntu 20.04 by using `nm-connection-editor`. For whatever reason, the option doesn't appear anymore in neither the Wifi/Ethernet nor the VPN config UIs.

1. Open a terminal
2. Type `nm-connection-editor`
3. Select the network connection you want to auto-connect

   [image: Network connections selection window, settings button in red]
4. Click the gear icon to open settings for that connection
5. Go to the General tab
6. Enable the `Automatically connect to VPN` option and select the VPN in the dropdown menu to the right

   [image: Network configuration window, general tab, auto-connect option in red]
7. Click Save

Comment: Such a great answer!  Thank you midopa!

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer terminals, you can use `nmcli`,
I did it using the following commands:

First, find and open the VPN connection you want to update

```
➜  ~ nmcli c show --active |grep vpn
MyVPN           115ae594-aa91-4d13-8c92-421af245f935  vpn     wlp61s0         
➜  ~ nmcli c edit MyVPN
```

This will open the nmcli prompt, from here you can query the values and set them, like this:

```
===| nmcli interactive connection editor |===
...
nmcli> print connection.autoconnect
connection.autoconnect: no
nmcli> set connection.autoconnect yes
nmcli> save persistent
Saving the connection with 'autoconnect=yes'. That might result in an immediate activation of the connection.
Do you still want to save? (yes/no) [yes] yes
Connection 'MyVPN' (115ae594-aa91-4d13-8c92-421af245f935) successfully updated.
```

And you should be done!

Comment: Only option that worked for me. On a side note, if you know its name, you can just `grep` it without having to connect it first by dropping the `--active`.

Answer (score 3):

> If I remember correctly it worked for a while and doesn't anymore.

- This might be obvious, but sometimes I don't think of it. Did you try reinstallation like:

  sudo apt-get purge network-manager-vpn
  sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc
  Then:
  [image]

> Now I want this VPN connection to automatically activate when I'm in a certain wireless network.

- There's a way to suppress the "couldn't connect"-type of messages when your users are in the wrong network, but can't remember how it went. I see no other way to automatically connect in a graphical way. Maybe you'll have to write a script doing the connecting when in said wlan-network.

Hope that helped.

Comment: I still haven't come around to actually testing this. I'll mark it answered when I will. Promise.

Comment: in my experience this doesn't actually work. I believe this to be a bug in NetworkManager

Comment: Yep this is broken, even in Precise. It doesn't connect automatically O_o

Comment: Yup -- broken. Does not work (Ubunutu 12.04).

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm this following solution working for me. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I went to the shutdown icon and then system settings.

When the settings screen opens, I went to 'Network' and the WiFi network with which I was connected. There is a small arrow one one side of the name of the network.

[image: Settings screen shot, its in Arabic]

Click that icon and you should see an option called "settings" or "options" (or something similar) here:

[image: Click settings]

When the next window opens, simply go to the 'General' tab and you should see an option that gives you an option to Automatically connect to a VPN. Choose the VPN You'd like to connect when connected to this WiFi, and boom! Everytime you connect to this network, Ubuntu will also connect you to that VPN. :)

For me its working. I hope it works for everyone else too.
Doesn't require any sort of text editor or code editor or anything..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any dispatcher scripts any more ! In 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) you just have to take the following steps after setting the autoconnect option in the NetworkManager GUI.

Store the vpn-secrets plainly in the config file for the VPN-connection under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/YourVPNConnectionName`.

You can achieve this by setting `IPSec secret-flags=0` and `Xauth password-flags=0` in the config file. Then go to the NetworkManager GUI and save again you VPN-connection settings. Now a section called [vpn-secrets] should be present in the config file. Doublecheck it and autoconnection should be working now !

Answer (score 1):

Even though the man page lists `nmcli con status` as a valid command, The above solution provided by [`Hugo Heden`](https://askubuntu.com/a/90888/570982) returns an error `"Error: Object 'status' is unknown, try 'nmcli help'"`

I'm using nmcli 1.2.2 (`nmcli -v`) and I've tested and modified the following for `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/vpn-up` and it worked like a charm.

```
#! /bin/bash

REQUIRED_CONNECTION_NAME="<name-of-connection>"
VPN_CONNECTION_NAME="<name-of-vpn-connection>"


default_conn=$(nmcli con show --active | grep "${REQUIRED_CONNECTION_NAME}")
vpn_conn=$(nmcli con show id | grep "${VPN_CONNECTION_NAME}")
if [ "${default_conn}" -a ! "${vpn_conn}" ];
then
    nmcli con up id "${VPN_CONNECTION_NAME}"
fi
```

Note: You can use `nmcli con show` to see all connection names as they aren't always the same as what's listed in the Network Connections GUI

Comment: The OP is asking about Ubuntu.

Comment: Kali and Ubuntu are both Debian based so the solution is often the same. I just went ahead and tested this on an Ubuntu 15.10 instance and the nmcli error was the same as I'd mentioned above. The solution worked just the same as well. The nmcli version installed on the 15.10 box is 1.0.4.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the uuid of the VPN profile by using the "secondaries" field in your primary connection

For example, `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired`

```
[connection]
id=Wired
uuid=95ad54f8-9d72-3e65-a4a7-b106aa310eed
type=ethernet
secondaries=66ecf287-8b26-413b-86f2-caca7608bc67;
```

Reference https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nm-settings.html

Answer (score 0):

Use following Python script [Gist #1547663](https://gist.github.com/1547663).

First parameter to the script is VPN connection name in NetworkManager and the second is comma separated names of networks that should be ignored (e.g. using VPN connection at home is useless).

Example to install and let it run at boot time:

```
git clone git://gist.github.com/1547663.git /home/user/autovpn/
echo "python /home/user/autovpn/autovpn.py 'myvpn' 'Auto homenetwork,Auto worknetwork' > /var/log/autovpn.log&" > /etc/rc.local
/etc/rc.local
```

Now if you connect to a network (either wifi or ethernet), it will also try to setup VPN connection.

Comment: I think this approach is less elegant, due to a background process being active for this all the time, while it could be event-driven like in the answer of @hugoheden.

Comment: It does more than his answer: it also handles VPN reconnect and cases where user manually disables vpn connection (meaning it shouldn't try to reconnect VPN in that case)

Answer (score 0):

Updating Hugo's answer. Works well on Ubuntu 20.04

```
#! /bin/bash

REQUIRED_CONNECTION_NAME="<name-of-connection>"
VPN_CONNECTION_NAME="<name-of-vpn-connection>"


activ_con=$(nmcli c s --active | grep "${REQUIRED_CONNECTION_NAME}")
activ_vpn=$(nmcli c s --active | grep "${VPN_CONNECTION_NAME}")
if [ "${activ_con}" -a ! "${activ_vpn}" ];
then
    nmcli con up id "${VPN_CONNECTION_NAME}"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above mentioned solutions might not properly work with WireGuard VPNs, at least not as far as `Debian 12 Bookworm` with `KDE` since there are still open  Issues because WireGuard is a `device` not an `vpn` as far as I understood it:

- [Ubuntu Issue Report](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+question/703893)
- [Freedesktop Bug Report](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/205)

So i made a bash script inspired from the answers here for Wireguard which also allows to define multiple WLANs at once and a "Paranoid Mode". I specifically only test one WLAN interface (since I have another one for a virtual machine):

1. Create a `99-vpn-up.conf`in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/`
2. Make it executable `chmod +x 99-vpn-up.conf`

Bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Configuration (change these)
WLAN="wl...."           # Interface name of WLAN adapter (find it with 'ip a'...)
VPN_NAME="FOOBAR..."        # VPN Connection name (Name from Network Manager)
CON="HandyHotspot|PublicWLAN|...."      # Connection names, separated multiple connection names with a pipe '|'

# Get parameters from the dispatcher (see 'man NetworkManager-dispatcher' for all the different states)
interface=$1 status=$2


if [ "$interface" = "$WLAN" ]; then
    # If the interface is the WLAN adapter, check the status
    case $status in
    up)
        # In case the interface got started, check if it is one of our defined WLAN Connections
        if nmcli con show --active | grep -Eqs "$CON"; then
            # Start the VPN Connection if it is not already running
            if ! nmcli con show --active | grep -qs "$VPN_NAME"; then
                 nmcli connection up id "$VPN_NAME"
            fi
        fi
    ;;
    down)
        # In case the interface got stopped, disable the VPN connection if it is active
        # In the case from switching from a defined WLAN to an undefined, this script is run twice 
        #so it 'should' not start another VPN Connection
        if nmcli con show --active | grep -qs "$VPN_NAME"; then
            nmcli connection down id "$VPN_NAME"
        fi
    ;;
    esac
fi

# "Paranoid Mode" :-) 
# Uncomment the following lines if you want to restart the VPN in case it 
# gets deactivated while still connected to a WLAN defined above - basicall disables non-VPN WLANs
# Wireguard is a "device" so "down" has to be used, for other VPNs "vpn-down" has to be used (did not test)

#if [ "$interface" = "$VPN_NAME" ]; then
#   case $status in
#   down)
#       # Restart the VPN again in case on of the defined WLANs is still active
#       if nmcli con show --active | grep -Eqs "$CON"; then
#           nmcli connection up id "$VPN_NAME"
#       fi
#   ;;
#   esac
#fi
```