# Why after ticking Automatically connect to VPN the Ethernet is not activated automatically anymore?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I have configured an OpenVPN session attached to my Ethernet Wired Connection and as soon as I have ticked the option "Automatically connect to VPN when using this connection" on my Wired Connection 1, the Ethernet is not activated automatically anymore by the login script and I have to do it manually. It works fine manually but I'd like to have it done automatically after startup. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good answer regarding this question (it's due to a bug) and a workaround in 
[this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86365/how-can-i-have-my-vpn-connect-automatically-when-the-wireless-connects)