# Bionic: How can I automatically enable VPN on a network connection?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, vpn

In Xenial 16.04, I was able to use Network Manager to configure a VPN to autostart per network connection.

In Bionic 18.04, I can't yet find this option.

Is it available via some configuration or additional package?

See also: https://askubuntu.com/a/1033606/11052 and [Automatically turn on VPN on computer unlock Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033278/automatically-turn-on-vpn-on-computer-unlock-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 5):

While Gnome 3's connection editor doesn't (as of writing) offer the option, it's possible to configure this via `nm-connection-editor` as before in 16.04

See [Automatically turn on VPN on computer unlock Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033278/automatically-turn-on-vpn-on-computer-unlock-ubuntu-18-04) for instructions - the question talks about unlocking, but the answer applies to other network connection changes too.