# How do I autoconnect to VPN in Lubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, autostart

I am a Linux newbie, tech oldie...

I have configured `openvpn` in network manager for the connections offered by my VPN.

On the one I want to auto connect, I ticked the box to have it auto connect.  This does not work, and googling says it is a well known problem...

By searching, I found that if I type this in the terminal, it will connect to my VPN as desired:

```
nmcli con up uuid e1e8cc82-c766-483f-a102-33e265fd7cfd
```

I then found that lubuntu 12.04 uses `/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart` to start applications at startup for all users.

I have tried adding the above, with and without a preceding @ symbol.

Neither works.  Please help a newbie out...

Answer (score 0):

It is most probably a problem with your vpn-secrets. Here comes a possible solution:
[store your secrets plainly](https://askubuntu.com/a/475667/286969)