# How to have my IPVanish connection to auto start when ubuntu boot up?

Tags: vpn

I am trying to have my VPN connection to auto start when I open my Laptop. Right now it is working perfectly fine, but I have to go and click on it every time. I already look into the network manager and there is no place that I can click on run on startup or something similar.
Looking more for a command line to run it automatically. I am using IPVanish.

Thank You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automatically connect to VPN with Network-Manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43465/how-to-automatically-connect-to-vpn-with-network-manager)

Comment: Do you have, or can you get, .ovpn files for your VPN connections from the IPVanish web site? Do you use an IPVanish app to connect?

Comment: What VPN are you using?